# Is it possible to derive Reynold's transport equation intuitively just from ordinary derivative definition?

Tags: calculus, integration, fluid-dynamics, divergence-operator, divergence-theorem

So I've recently started looking into where do Navier-Stokes equations come from and I've learned lots of interesting stuff so far but I stopped at Reynold's transport equation, which states that:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\iiint L dV = \iiint \frac{\delta L}{\delta t} dV + \iint L(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{n})dA$$, where L is some property transferred with the fluid, $\vec{u}$ is velocity field, $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector pointing outside of given volume bounded by infinitesimal $dA$.

So I tried deriving this by myself starting from just the ordinary derivative of mass over dt. Note that I'd like to derive transport of density of fluid **assuming incompressibility condition**.

First let's define our mass scalar field as $$m(x(t), y(t), z(t), t)$$ Then:
$$\frac{dm}{dt} = \frac{\delta m}{\delta t} + \frac{\delta m}{\delta x} \frac{\delta x}{\delta t} + \frac{\delta m}{\delta y} \frac{\delta y}{\delta t} + \frac{\delta m}{\delta z} \frac{\delta z}{\delta t}$$
For fluids $\vec{u} = (\frac{\delta x}{\delta t}, \frac{\delta y}{\delta t}, \frac{\delta z}{\delta t})$
Therefore:
$$\frac{dm}{dt} =  \frac{\delta m}{\delta t} + (\nabla m)\vec{u}$$ which is material derivative...
Now we want to enforce the conservation of mass so that the following is true: $$\frac{dm}{dt} = 0$$
$$\frac{\delta m}{\delta t} = - (\nabla m)\vec{u} = -\nabla (\rho V)\vec{u}$$
And now comes the surprising thing which I'm not sure is true (maybe I did some mistake sin my understanding?)... **My question is whether the following is actually true**:
$$ -\nabla (\rho V)\vec{u} = - \iiint \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{u} ) dV$$
If this is true indeed then we can use divergence theorem to get:
$$\iiint \frac{\delta \rho}{\delta t} dV  = \frac{\delta m}{\delta t} = -\nabla (\rho V)\vec{u} = - \iiint \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{u} ) dV = - \iint \rho \vec{u} \cdot \vec{n} dA$$
$$\iiint \frac{\delta \rho}{\delta t} dV = - \iint \rho \vec{u} \cdot \vec{n} dA$$
which is Reynold's transport equation for fluid density without $\frac{d}{dt}\iiint L dV $ term since it zeroes out due to conservation of mass principle.
Is my reasoning correct with all of the above? If so, how would you intuitively (or mathematically) justify the equation below? $$ -\nabla (\rho V)\vec{u} = - \iiint \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{u} ) dV$$
Thanks for any time you spend reading my post ;)

Comment: Rigorous proof of the Reynolds transport theorem is given [here](https://www.planetmath.org/reynoldstransporttheorem) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1920155/148510).  It is understandable to look for an  intuitive explanation. But this "intuitive derivation" is not based on sound principles of continuum mechanics used in the development of the Navier-Stokes equations. That starts with a continuum hypothesis that posits a smooth density field $\rho(x,t)$ such that the mass of fluid enclosed in a moving (material) region $\Omega(t)$ is $\int_{\Omega(t)} \rho(x,t) \, dV$.

Comment: There is no "mass scalar field".  The mass of the fluid at a point in space with location specified by the point $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is zero -- since integration of the density over a region with zero content is zero.  Also your equation $-\nabla (\rho V)\vec{u} = - \iiint \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec{u} ) dV$ carries no meaning.  What does $V$ represent on the LHS?  The LHS might be a dyadic product of a gradient (vector) and the velocity vector but the RHS is the integral of a scalar field.  Furthermore there is no region of integration indicated.

Comment: ah so my derivation was wrong since they very first assumption about mass field. I see now that it makes no sense. I skipped the integration regions since I incorrectly assumed it's not that relevant for derivation itself but I saw your answer in that post you linked and realized I was wrong. Thank you for your answer!