# Two time derivatives of kinetic energy of fluid

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, continuum-theory

Suppose $D$ is a smooth domain, $\rho > 0$ is fluid density (constant) and $u \in C^1([0,1];D)$ is the fluid velocity.  Let $K(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int_D \rho \vert u \vert^2 dV,~0\le t \le 1,$ be the kinetic energy of the incompressible fluid.

On the one hand, by Reynolds Transport Theorem,
\begin{align}
\label{1}
\frac{d}{dt} K(t) = \int_D \rho \dot{u} \cdot u dV,
\end{align}
where $\dot{u} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + (\nabla u)u$ is the material derivative.
On the other hand, by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem,
\begin{align}
\label{2}
\frac{d}{dt} K(t) = \int_D \rho \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \cdot u dV. 
\end{align}

The first calculation is used in Equation (6.42) page 254 of [Oscar Gonzalez and Andrew M. Stuart - A First Course in Continuum Mechanics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/first-course-in-continuum-mechanics/DC9A87155531958AD5EFC66AEB981DAE), while the second one is used in Equation (1.3.2) page 7 of [Charles R. Doering and J. D. Gibbon - Applied Analysis of the Navier-Stokes Equations](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/applied-analysis-of-the-navierstokes-equations/C413964F37F2EE606669FEB49C51A454).

Which one is correct, or am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Both are correct. The difference between the right hand sides is $\int_D \rho [(u\cdot \nabla)u] \cdot u dV$ which is zero. You can show this using integration by parts (note that incompressible and constant density means $\nabla\cdot u = 0$ by the continuity equation).

Comment: @Winther Thank you, but I still don't get it. Here is my attempt: since $[(u \cdot \nabla)u] u = \frac{1}{2} u \cdot \nabla \left( \lvert u \rvert^2\right)$, by IBPs, $\int_D [(u \cdot \nabla)u] u dV = -  \frac{1}{2} \int_D  \lvert u \rvert^2 (\nabla \cdot u) dV + \frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial D} (u \cdot n)  \lvert u \rvert^2 d A$. Thus the first term vanishes by $\nabla \cdot u = 0$. However, how do we get $u \cdot n = 0$? Here $n$ is the outward unit normal vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on the nature of the domain $D$. If the domain $D(t)$ is time-dependent where $\mathbf{u}^{(b)}(\mathbf{x})$ is the velocity of an area element at the boundary point $\mathbf{x} \in \partial D(t)$, then according to Reynolds transport theorem (proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1920155/148510)) and an application of the divergence theorem, we have

$$\tag{1}\frac{dK}{dt} = \int_{D(t)} \frac{\partial K}{\partial t}\, dV + \int_{ D(t)}\nabla \cdot \left(K\mathbf{u}^{(b)}\right)  \, dV \\=  \int_{D(t)} \frac{\partial K}{\partial t}\, dV + \int_{\partial D(t)}K\left(\mathbf{u}^{(b)}\cdot \mathbf{n}\right)   \, dA$$

There are three possibilities.

(i) We have an arbitrary moving domain with some prescribed boundary velocity $\mathbf{u}^{(b)}$ and (1) cannot be simplified further without more information.

(ii) We have a solid stationary boundary where $\mathbf{u}^{(b)} \cdot \mathbf{n}$ holds at every boundary point either as a consequence of the no-slip condition for a viscous fluid or the impermeability condition for an inviscid fluid.  In this case (1) reduces to
$$\tag{2}\frac{dK}{dt} = \int_{D(t)} \frac{\partial K}{\partial t}\, dV $$

(iii) The domain is a material element where $\mathbf{u}^{(b)}= \mathbf{u}$, that is
the velocity at the boundary is the fluid velocity. In this case,

$$\tag{3}\frac{dK}{dt} = \int_{D(t)} \frac{\partial K}{\partial t}\, dV + \int_{\partial D(t)}K\left(\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{n}\right)   \, dA$$
Again,  the ambiguity of $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{n}$ remains.

---

In the above discussion nothing was said about the incompressiblity of the fluid and the condition $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$, because it was not necessary to derive either form of the Reynolds transport theorem shown in (1).

What you show in your first equation

$$\frac{d}{dt} K(t) = \int_D \rho \dot{u} \cdot u \, dV,$$

is a consequence of the Reynolds transport theorem given both incompressiblity and the specific form $K = \frac{1}{2} \rho |\mathbf{u}|^2$. This follows form

$$ \frac{\partial K}{\partial t} +\nabla \cdot (K\mathbf{u}) = \frac{\partial K}{\partial t}  + \underbrace{K \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}}_{= 0} + (\mathbf{u} \cdot\nabla)K \\ = \frac{\rho}{2} \frac{\partial }{\partial t} (\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u}) + \frac{\rho}{2}(\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) (\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u}) = \rho \frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t} \cdot \mathbf{u} + \rho \left[(\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{u} \right] \cdot \mathbf{u} \\ := \rho \dot{u}\cdot u$$

However, this special form does not make it any clearer why the two forms you present should be equal in all circumstances.

Comment: Thank you, that resolves my confusion. I just have one more question. Consider an inviscid fluid in a fixed domain, by definition of fluid velocity, i.e. $u(x,t)= \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\varphi (X,t) \big\vert_{X=\psi (x,t)}$, do we also have the no-slip boundary condition $u=0$? Here $\varphi$ is the deformation map and $\psi=\varphi^{-1}$.

Comment: @macnguyen: You're welcome.  For a viscous fluid we always assume that the no-slip condition holds at a solid boundary. It is a physically reasonable assumption given that viscous stresses are at work.  In an inviscid fluid the no-slip condition does not hold.  The problem of solving the Euler equations (for inviscid fluids) becomes overdetermined when no-slip is imposed.  Instead the problem is well-posed with the assumption of no flux $u \cdot n  = 0$ at a solid impermeable boundary. In inviscid flow the tangential velocity component at a solid surface may not vanish.

Comment: In terms of deformation maps in a Lagrangian setting we would say that fluid particles can move along the surface, but cannot penetrate.