# Why does $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\int_V\rho u_i\text{ d}V=\int_V\left(\frac{Du_i}{Dt}\right)\rho\text{ d}V$?

Tags: physics, fluid-dynamics

*Preamble (updated)*

My course notes have

> Now consider a closed volume $V$ in the fluid which is bounded by a surface $S$. Let $V$ move with the fluid, so no fluid moves in or out of $V$. [...] Now $\rho\text{ d}V$ is the mass of a fluid element and does not change as the element moves around. Thus $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_V\rho u_i\text{ d}V=\int_V\left(\frac{Du_i}{Dt}\right)\rho\text{ d}V.\tag{$\ast$}$$

Earlier it was stated that

> In this course we will be assuming that fluids are incompressible

and the substantive derivative $\frac{D}{Dt}$ was defined, with a note that

> Sometimes it is written as $\frac{d}{dt}$.

*Question (updated)*

I gather from TedShifrin's helpful comments that $V$ is not independent of $t$. So that leaves me wondering how the (or a) derivative operator gets inside the integral. It's not simply undoing the integration, and if it's doing something fancier I can't immediately see what that is. Could anyone give me a pointer on that?

---

*Question (original - ignore if you like)*

I see that $V$ doesn't depend on $t$, so we can take the differentiation operator inside the integral to get
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_V\rho u_i\text{ d}V
& = \int_V\frac{d}{dt}(\rho u_i)\text{ d}V \\
& = \int_Vu_i\frac{d\rho}{dt}+\rho\frac{du_i}{\text{d}t}\text{ d}V \\
& = \int_V\frac{du_i}{dt}\rho\text{ d}V, \text{ since } \rho=\text{const.}
\end{align}

For this to align with $(\ast)$, I think either $\frac{d}{dt}$ must be the substantive derivative $\frac{D}{Dt}$, for some reason being written in both forms in the same equation, or we must have \begin{align}
& \begin{aligned}[t]
\frac{du_i}{dt}
& = \frac{Du_i}{Dt} \\
& = \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t}+\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla u_i
\end{aligned} \\[1em]
\therefore\;& \frac{du_i}{dt} = \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t}, \hspace{1em} \textbf{u}\cdot\nabla u_i = 0.
\end{align}

Further down, $\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla u_i$ is used in a way that I think means it doesn't have to be zero in this context, which seems to point to the use of both notations for the substantive derivative in the same equation. Is that what's happened?

---

Comment: The substantive derivative arises because the region is not fixed. So be careful: Is $V$ really fixed?

Comment: @TedShifrin A few lines above is "Now consider a closed volume $V$ in the fluid which is bounded by a surface $S$. Let $V$ move with the fluid, so no fluid moves in or out of $V$.". Doesn't that mean $V$ is time-invariant with respect to its fluid content?

Comment: Yes. The volume $V$ is flowing along with the fluid, deforming with time so that the fluid flux across the boundary is $0$. In particular, your “I see that $V$ doesn’t depend on $t$” is not right.

Comment: @TedShifrin For the record, I think your "Yes." is in response to the original phrasing of my question, which was "Does this, or do you, mean that $V$ is a function of $t$?". Could you give me a hint as to how to proceed? I'm still not sure if $\frac{d}{dt}$ is a total or a substantive derivative. If $\rho\text{ d}V$ is constant, that leaves us... differentiating $\int_Vu_i$ with no variable of integration?

Comment: My interpretation is that $d/dt$ on the left is the net time derivative, as everything, including $V$, varies with $t$. My “yes” was confusing. What do you mean by “$V$ is time-invariant”? I would write $V_t$ for clarity. Even if $\rho$ is constant,  conservation of mass does not indicate that the region is fixed; in this case, its volume would be constant, but not its shape.

Comment: @TedShifrin I haven't heard 'net derivative' before but I'll guess it's synonymous with 'total derivative'. I think what I meant by "$V$ is time-invariant" is "$V$ is not a function of $t$". For me $V_t$ is awkward since I'm used to that meaning $\partial V/\partial t$; I'll guess you intend it to show that $V$ is a function of time, which I'm used to writing as $V(t)$. So suppose $d/dt$ is a net/total derivative and $V=V(\textbf{x},t)$ is a function of time and position; then are we doing some sort of chain plus product rule on the integral?

Comment: Because $D/Dt$ includes the (instantaneous) effect of $V$’s moving. There are various texts that treat this stuff reasonably carefully. One that I happen to know is Shawn Walker’s *The Shape of Things*.

Comment: When $V$ is a time-dependent "material control volume" that is convected with the fluid velocity the substantive derivative will appear inside the integral. See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1920155/148510) for a rigorous derivation.

Comment: @RRL Thanks for this. If anything, that's more of an answer than I was expecting. Do you know if a somewhat simpler explanation is possible, perhaps with simplifying assumptions (e.g. fixing some variables, such as $\rho\text{ d}V$ as my course notes say)? It strikes me as a bit odd that the notes would replace this much justification with 'thus'.